# how to set duration for individual SKTextures in animation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2, sktexture

I am trying to set duration for individual `SKTextures` in an animation. Below the  `armsAtlas` texture atlas. I would like to set the `upTexture` to last between 1-4 seconds randomly followed by the `downTexture` to last between 0.3 - 1 second.  How can I set these duration ranges for the individual textures?

```
let armsAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "arms")
let downTexture = armsAtlas.textureNamed("down")
let upTexture = armsAtlas.textureNamed("up")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SKAction sequence and it's waitForDuration:withRange: method, like this:

```
//By default, the sprite is initialized with downTexture
let sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: downTexture)
sprite.position = CGPoint(x: 200, y: 200)
addChild(sprite)
let sequence = SKAction.sequence([

    SKAction.runBlock({NSLog("Up texture set")}), //Added just for debugging to print a current time
    SKAction.setTexture(upTexture),
    SKAction.waitForDuration(2.5, withRange: 3.0),  //Wait between 1.0 and 4.0 seconds
    SKAction.runBlock({NSLog("Down texture set")}),
    SKAction.setTexture(downTexture),
    SKAction.waitForDuration(0.65, withRange: 0.7),//Wait between 0.3 and 1.0 seconds
    ])

let action = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)

sprite.runAction(action, withKey: "aKey")
```

What this code does, is that it creates a sprite, initialize it with downTexture by default and:

- swap texture to upTexture immediately
- waits between 1 and 4 seconds
- swap texture to downTexture
- waits between 0.3 and 1 seconds
- repeats all this forever

If you want to stop this action, you can access it like this:

```
if sprite.actionForKey("aKey") != nil {
            removeActionForKey("aKey")
}
```

Comment: shouldn't your range be double? `SKAction.waitForDuration(2.5, withRange: 3),  //Wait between 1.0 and 4.0 seconds` since the random will calculate upto +- 1/2 the range valie

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yup, you are right. Thanks for pointing that.

Comment: No problem, that gets every time as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this.

You could use `SKAction` delay to swap randomly between them...

```
func setTexture(texture: SKTexture, delay: NSTimeInterval, range: NSTimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let textureAction = SKAction.setTexture(texture)
    let delayAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(delay, withRange: range)
    return SKAction.sequence([delayAction, textureAction])
}
```

No set up the action to switch between the two...

```
let downAction = setTexture(downTexture, delay: 0.65, range: 0.35)
let upAction = setTexture(upTexture, delay: 2.5, range: 1.5)
let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([downAction, upAction])
let repeatAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceAction)

yourTexturedSprite.runAction(repeatAction)
```

Comment: @Forgmeister SKAction.waitForDuration accepts NSTimeInterval, for both delay, and range parameters.

Comment: @Whirlwind edited now, NSTimeInterval is just an alias for double (although I used float incorrectly) so they can be changed with no issues. Better to keep the actual named type though :D

Comment: @Forgemeister  There are actually few more errors with your code. 1. you can't use repeat keyword as an constant (or variable) name. 2. Third parameter (range) must be labeled in this case.

Comment: @Whirlwind that's what you get for writing code in a browser window with no code checking. lol

Comment: @Whirlwind also, names are auto completed when you type the first letter. Just hit tab to select the name.

Comment: @Forgemeister I am aware of what you are saying, but because of beginners, who will  likely just copy and paste the code, it is better to remove those errors. After all, those were errors.

Comment: @Whirlwind no, I mean names on StackOverflow. Like my name. Fogmeister. You've got it wrong every time you replied. Just type @ and then the first letter. :)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I see...Well sometimes it doesn't work for me after I enter "at" sign (maybe it's because of my browser), so I just write it manually. :).

Comment: @Whirlwind ah, if it doesn't pop up an auto complete it's because that person will get a notification anyway :D (Normally because there is only one person or they are the OP). :)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks :) The author of the post will always be notified, so no need for @name (like I was doing).